# HTML5 audio file not showing in IE11

Tags: html, audio, mp3, internet-explorer-11

I am having strange issue regarding HTML5 audio tag.
I have used HTML5 audio tag for displaying "mp3" files in my site. They get displayed properly in IE9 & IE10,but showing error like "Invalid Source" in IE11.
Operating system is Windows 7(32 bit).I don't know the exact reason behind it.Plese help.

Following is the screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @CsharpBeginner I provided an answer if you're still wondering

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue where IE11 now requires users to enable Play Sounds in Webpage setting under Multimedia settings. There is no programmatic fix for this.  You can warn IE11 users about this setting.